# Is 3.days.from_now same as 72.hours_from_now when we schedule a task in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler, sidekiq

I want to schedule a task to run 3 days from now, in Sidekiq. Is there any difference when I use `3.days.from_now` instead of `72.hours.from_now` while calling the `perform_in` function on the worker?

Answer (score 1):

No difference, both will return you the same result

```
3.days.from_now
#=> Mon, 12 Jun 2017 04:35:34 EDT -04:00

72.hours.from_now
#=> Mon, 12 Jun 2017 04:35:34 EDT -04:00
```

Even

```
(72*60).minutes.from_now
#=> Mon, 12 Jun 2017 04:35:34 EDT -04:00

# OR

4320.minutes.from_now
#=> Mon, 12 Jun 2017 04:35:34 EDT -04:00
```

It's just what you prefer to use and which is easy to read